# Install graph-tool on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, port, graph-tool

I'm trying to install [graph-tool](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/download#macos) on OSX 10.8

Commands:

```
$ port install py-graph-tool
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-graph-tool
--->  Building py27-graph-tool
```

and no response in more than 30min, not building anything either.

Have I done something wrong, or is there any way to see more logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is too late for me to help you, but the answer can help other people: I'm on a macbook air with Os X 10.8, and it seems it takes a while, up to an hour, for graph tool to be built and installed. 
So, as you probably have already seem, you just need to wait a little longer.

Comment: Indeed, graph-tool takes a while to be built. It takes 26 minutes on my Mac Pro 2,66 GHz Quad-Core.

Answer (score 0):

It took me more than an hour to successfully install the package. I'm running OSX V10.9.2 on a machine with Processor 2.3GHz i7 and 8GB memory. Yes, it takes some time.